# VBA Collection retrieves data but does not show values

Tags: excel, vba, file, collections

My question is about Collections.

In this code, I open each other excel within the folder of my current excel and retrieve all its data for the first column into a Collection.

Then, I try to insert the collected values in my current file.

When I use coll.count, the count is the correct one, so I believe the data is efectively being collected.

I have used the form of 'Sheet.cells.value=coll(i)' before and has worked perfectly, but in this case it doesn't.

An Error 1004 appears - 'Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error' in that line.

Would you have any ideas as to why?
Any recommendation?

Thank you!

```
Option Explicit
Sub LoopThroughFolder()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'State variables
Dim Path As String          'path of folder
Dim DataBase As String      ' current excel file
Dim ERow As Long            'last row of current excel file
Dim coll As New Collection  'collection of data
Dim iRow As Long            'rows of other excel files
Dim n As Long               'total records of other excel files
Dim i As Integer


'Name of files to open
Path = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\")
DataBase = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'For each file
Do While Path <> DataBase

        'Open, retrieve data, close
        Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Path)
        n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
            For iRow = 2 To n
            coll.Add Cells(iRow, 1)
            Next iRow
        ActiveWorkbook.Close

    'Next file
    Path = Dir
    Loop

'Now place the values in my current excel file (here is the problem)(?)
ERow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To coll.Count
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ERow + i, 1).Value = coll(i)
    Next i

'End
Set coll = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
 ActiveSheet.Cells(ERow + i, 1).Value = coll(i)
```

with:

```
 ActiveSheet.Cells(ERow + i, 1).Value = coll.Item(i)
```

*(there may be other issues)*

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change `coll.Add Cells(iRow, 1)` to `coll.Add Cells(iRow, 1).Value` and it will start working.

further it is better to give some wild card in 1st dir statement like '`Path = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")`'

Also `Do While Path <> DataBase` may cause to terminate the loop once Database is encountered. It is be better to do this like

```
   Do While Path <> ""
        If Path <> DataBase Then
        '''''''''''''''  
        '''''''''''''' 
        End If
    Path = Dir
    Loop
```

Comment: Thank you!, yes, adding ".value" was part of the solution.  I will take the advice on the loop!